# Class subclass type with a public method

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand why in Subclass definition a public method is involved

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

**Source code of the RecyclerView.ViewHolder**

```
public abstract static class ViewHolder {


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        if (itemView == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("itemView may not be null");
        }
        this.itemView = itemView;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is why does the following code appear to call a public method `ViewHolder` within `RecylcerView`.  Here is your code, with a slight rename to make things clearer:

```
class MyClass(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

And what is missing from your description is showing the outer class:

```java
class RecyclerView {                           // outer/containing class
    static class ViewHolder {                  // nested class
         public ViewHolder(ViewItem view) {    // constructor
              // ... constructor body
         }
    }
}
```

Now looking at that nesting, to talk about the `ViewHolder` class you need to reference it as `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.  Then if you want to construct an instance of that you must add the constructor parameters, for example in Java:

```java
new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view);
```

In Kotin when you descend from a class, your constructor must call the super constructor and the short hand for that is to do it in the declaration.

```
class MyClass(ViewItem view) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // ...class body
}
```

This says `MyClass` descends from `ViewHolder` which is a nested class of `RecyclerView` and the constructor parameter coming into `MyClass` constructor is being passed into the super constructor of `ViewHolder`.

This is the same as Java:

```java
class MyClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public MyClass(ViewItem view) {
        super(view);
    }
}
```

You can also import the nested static class directly, then drop the `RecyclerView` prefix, but it is a bit clearer to leave it.